# How to copy database file from asset folder to /data/data/<package-name>/database folder

Tags: android

I have put a database file in to assets folder and want to copy it to /data/data//database folder . For this purpose , I have written the following code :

```
public void copy()
{
    try
    {
        String dest_path = "/data/data/"+getPackageName()+"/database/sultandatabase";
        File f = new File(dest_path);
        if( !f.exists() )
        {
            copy_database(getBaseContext().getAssets().open(db_name),new FileOutputStream(dest_path));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Sorry the file can not be opended", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}

public void copy_database(InputStream io ,OutputStream ou) throws Exception
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024] ;
    int lenght;

    while( ( lenght = io.read(buffer)) > 0 )
        ou.write(buffer);
    io.close();
    ou.close();

}
```

When I call copy() the database file is not copied . What is the possible reason ?? How can I fix this ??  Instead a toast is shown up . That means my program gets Exception ?? But why ??

Comment: Are you sure you have permission in your manifest to use device/external storage?

Comment: No . Can you plz tell me about this ??

Comment: Here I simply copy two files . For that why I need to have permission ?

Comment: Sorry false alarm, the path you used is application-bound and should not require any permission.

Comment: Please consider using `SQLiteAssetHelper`, since it already works: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Comment: have you created the file and the folder you want to put your database in? I work with monodroid, and have my database under data/data/[package_name]/files/ instead of databases folder, anyway before copying my database I execute `SqliteConnection.CreateFile(dbPath);` and then copy where `dbPath` is the folder path data/data/[package_name]/files/database.db

Comment: Thanks to all . Actually I have done a mistake in this string_name : 

String dest_path = "/data/data/"+getPackageName()+"/database/sultandatabase";

It should be 

String dest_path = "/data/data/"+getPackageName()+"/databases/sultandatabase";

Answer (score 0):

i have this code for copy:

```
private void copyDataBase()
{
    try
    {
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
    String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0)
    {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```